# Update Value in SQL Table and Delete Redundant Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this database with the following tables that have many redundant records from various insert into table statements rather than updating the already existing data. Is there a way to delete the redundant records without losing the data in the table?

My code:

```
SELECT EMP_NUM,
       EMP_LNAME,
       EMP_FNAME,
       EMP_INITIAL,
       EMP_HIREDATE,
       JOB_CODE,
       EMP_PCT,
       PROJ_NUM
FROM EMP_2
```

My second question is I need to write the SQL code to change the `EMP_PCT` value to `3.85` for the person whose employee number (`EMP_NUM`) is `103`.

Comment: How would you determine which is redundant or not?

Comment: @ChristianR . . . This question appears to have two questions, which makes it too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to determine which records are reduntant and which ones should stay, there are two ways:

1. You don't care, so you can just do `select distinct` into some temporary table to get unique rows (so without redundancy), then delete the table and insert back unique vlues.
2. You have some column, upon which you decide which rows, from group of rows will be the one to preserve. For example you have `dateOfInsert` column,
   so you could use such query:

   ```
   select *, row_number() over (order by dateOfInsert desc) rn from MyTable
   ```

then, insert recrods to temporary table with `rn = 1`, delete the table, and insert only the newest records.

Regarding second question, it is basic:

```
update MyTable set EMP_PCT = 3.85 
where EMP_NUM = 103
```